# Problems with waking threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Good day!

I've meet problems with synchronizing threads in Java.

I have 3 processes ( i keep them in ConcurrentHashMap< Integer, Integer > man ) and 4 resources ( i keep them in ConcurrentHashMap< Integer, Integer > resourses ).

Each process can hold only 2 immediate resources. For example man[0] can hold only resources[0] and resources[1], man[1] can hold only resources[1] and resources[2] and etc.

So i have few situations when thread must wait till other threads will not release their resources. So this thread goes to wait... And it doesn't wake when i call notifyAll()!

What is wrong with my logic?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Philos
{
    private Thread thisThread;

public Philos()
{
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )                                          //Init processeses and resourses.
    {
        resourses.put( i, 0 );                                              //Each is free.
        man.put(i, 0);
    }
}


public void startThread( final int i )
{
    thisThread = new Thread()
    {
         public void run()
         {

             try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Eat( i );                                                   //Proc try to start work
                show( i, "Eat" );                                           //Show res and procs

                finishEat( i );                                             //Release resourses.
                show( i, "Release" );
                thisThread.interrupt();                                     //Finish threads
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Philos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
         }


    };

    thisThread.start();

}


private synchronized  void Eat( int i ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        testEat ( i );                                                          //Try to work.
        if ( !( man.get(i) == 1 ) )                                             //If proc are not working
        {
            System.out.printf("%d must wait\n", i);
            synchronized( Thread.currentThread() )                              //Put synchronize block to wait thread
            {
               Thread.currentThread().wait();                                   //Thread must wait
               System.out.println("Notifyied");
            }
        }

    }

private synchronized  void finishEat( int i ) throws InterruptedException
{
            man.put( i, 0 );                                                        //Release proc
            resourses.put(i,   0);                                                  //Release resourses of proc
            resourses.put(i+1, 0);
}


private synchronized  void testEat( int i ) throws InterruptedException
{
        System.out.printf("Test %d\n",i);
        if ( ( left(i) == 0 ) && ( right(i) == 0 ) )                            //If resourses availible
        {
            man.put( i, 1 );                                                    //Proc is busy
            resourses.put(i,   1);                                              //Resourses are busy
            resourses.put(i+1, 1);

            synchronized( Thread.currentThread() )
            {
                Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();                             //Notify al threads
            }
        }
}


private int left( int i )                                                   //Check left resourse.
    {
        return (resourses.get(i));
    }

    private int right( int i )                                                  //Check right resourse.
    {
        return (resourses.get(i+1));
    }

    private synchronized  void show( int i, String info )                       //Show info about resourses and proc
    {
        System.out.printf("\nid = %d, [%s]\n", i, info );

        System.out.println("Work[R]:");
        for ( int j = 1; j <= 4; j++ )                                          //Res
        {
            System.out.printf( "%d ", resourses.get(j) );
        }
        System.out.println();
        for ( int j = 1; j <= 4; j++ )                                          //Proc
        {
            System.out.printf( " %d", man.get(j) );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    private ConcurrentHashMap< Integer, Integer > resourses = new ConcurrentHashMap< Integer, Integer >();
    private ConcurrentHashMap< Integer, Integer > man = new ConcurrentHashMap< Integer, Integer >();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using join() instead of interrupt()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `wait()` and `notifyAll()` on a `Thread` object. That's not the way of doing things - you call it on some common object which all the relevant threads hold.

The fact that you're only *synchronizing* on the current thread in each case is also meaningless - nothing else is going to synchronize on that thread, so the synchronization is pointless.

You need to determine the common objects to synchronize/wait/notify. Typically I prefer to create separate objects solely for this purpose, but you *can* reuse existing objects too.

(I would also advise you not to call `Thread.interrupt` - it's unclear to me why you're doing that here...)

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, look at the higher-level abstractions in java.util.concurrent, such as [`Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), for a possibly-simpler way of achieving your goal.

Comment: Do you mean to create common object like

`private Object lock = new Object();`
And then use
`synchronized( lock )                              
 {
     wait();
 }`

and 

`synchronized( lock )                              
 {
      notifyAll();
 }`

Is it okey?

Comment: use a semaphore for that: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: @ExR: Nearly - but you'd call `lock.wait()` and `lock.notifyAll()`. As Thomas says, there are higher-level abstractions which you probably want to use though.